# How to document all npm dependencies from package.json into README.md

Tags: node.js, npm, markdown

I want to document all npm `devDependencies` and `dependencies` described in the `package.json` file into  the `README.md` file in the same project. Following properties are of interest `name`, `description` and `version`. Of course I could document this manually by checking package by package and documenting by hand, but are there any other automated approach to solve this?

**Edit**
You will only find `name` and `version` of each package in the `package.json` file. The `description` property needs to be retrieved from `npm`, for instance by executin CLI command `npm view <package name>` which returns json-formatted response. see more at https://docs.npmjs.com/api/npm

Comment: Why do you want to manually reproduce this information? Most of it already exists in relatively human-readable format in your `package.json` file, and package descriptions are only a quick command away. Putting it all into your README seems like overkill.

Comment: Hi Chris. `Description` property is missing for packages that are either in `devDependency` or `dependency` section of the `package.json`. Now, when you got quite a long list of dependencies and names of packages are not self explaining, then it might be hard to understand what packages is used for what purpose. Having the description property easy available would definitely be of help in that case.