# What dependencies to document?

Tags: documentation, dependency-management

Just to be clear, I'm not asking [how to add dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766444/how-to-document-all-npm-dependencies-from-package-json-into-readme-md) in a README.md, but rather, how to handle documenting them given my situation.

Looking at the [SO Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), I saw this as "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development," and I thought it appropriate to ask here.

**I need some guidance on a project.** To summarize... The project is a technology prototype for a small business, which I'll call "ACME," which contracted with me, and is using Raspberry Pis as a distributed client network to provide a service to their customers. The ACME's owner is not technical. He emphasized simplicity, extensibility, and stability for the project, and I want to avoid unnecessary confusion.

Where I'm becoming concerned is that while my direct dependencies are few, about two or three, my sub-dependencies are numerous. (To clarify, I'm coding the project in Node.js, with the exception of a few small C++ worker programs.) The modules I'm working with collectively sum up to about 40 sub-dependencies or greater.

**The most important thing to me is to do the right thing, especially with this being my first official job as a developer, and I'm all on my own with no senior developer to advise.**

So... should I only list my direct dependencies (which I would prefer, and which handle documenting their dependences themselves), or list all dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm` can list your dependencies just fine by itself (`npm ls`). What you need to document is *how to get the system up and running*, both as a user and as a developer (your successor or yourself in the future when you need to restore your dev setup from scratch).

EDIT: Additionally you will want to document how your own programs fit together as components in the whole system.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I had begun documenting how the programs all work together, but only informally... Now that I know this is the right way, I'll formalize it. But what do you mean by "how to get the system up and running"? I read that as (on the user side) as "what commands to type into terminal", and on the developer side as "this uses firebase, so make sure your server info is correct." Am I correct?

Comment: Yep, check this as a reference: https://github.com/iamstarkov/generator-zen